# libpng crashes on png_write_into (Windows 10, VS2013, self-built, all tests pass ok)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, libpng

I'm observing a crash due to an access violation in libpng (1.6.20) when calling png_write_info. I have built libpng from source (including zlib 1.2.8) and the png tests that come with the libpng source code all pass ok without any errors. I can confirm that good png files are being created during these tests.

The simple breakdown of my program (until where it crashes) looks like this. I have removed all error and bounds checking for simplicity reasons:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char* filename = argv[1];
    png_structp png = png_create_write_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    png_infop info = png_create_info_struct(png);
    if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png)))
    {
        abort();
    }

    // Output is 16-bit depth, greyscale format.
    png_set_IHDR(
        png,
        info,
        127, 127,
        16,
        PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY,
        PNG_INTERLACE_NONE,
        PNG_COMPRESSION_TYPE_DEFAULT,
        PNG_FILTER_TYPE_DEFAULT
    );

    // do the file stuff
    FILE *fp;
    errno_t error = fopen_s(&fp, filename, "wb");
    png_init_io(png, fp);
    png_write_info(png, info); // <-- crashes here with "access violation writing location ..."
```

Thanks for your help!

codeSourcerer

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got the answer to this one thanks to another question posted here:
[libpng crashes on png_read_info()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774265/libpng-crashes-on-png-read-info)

In there the answer is given by:

> If you don't use the Visual Studio defaults your application must still be built with the default runtime option (/MD). If, for some reason, it is not then your application will crash inside libpng16.dll as soon as libpng tries to read from a file handle you pass in.

So I recompiled my libpng with the properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Code Generation->Runtime Library set to Multi-Threaded DLL (/MD) (not the debug one!!)
and set the same for my png-writer project. Now it's working and does not crash anymore.

Cheers,
codeSourcerer

Comment: Now I am curious - how did you pass all the tests in your first attempt?

Comment: Well, the test programs that come with libpng as well as the libpng itself were all compiled with "Multi-Threaded DLL (/MD)", but my own program that uses libpng was not (it had "Multi-Threaded DLL debug (/MDd)"). The point is that whatever program uses libpng has to have the same "Runtime Library" setting as the libpng itself (/MD or /MDd).

Comment: Yep, I just tried it. If I compile the library's test program (pngtest) with a different "Runtime Library" option than the libpng itself, the test program fails as well.